# Error with AdaptiveCards in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

This problem occurred when I switched to NewTeams

Using Amazon S3, png files are being sent to the Teams channel in ‘AdaptiveCard’ type

AdaptiveCard's version is 1.5

The code I am using is as follows:

```
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            sendTeams = {
                "type": "message",
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                        "content": {
                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                            "version": "1.5",
                            "body": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Image",
                                    "url": "https://" + getattr(settings, "S3_BUCKET", None) + "/teams/" + '20230101'+ ".png",
                                    "size": "Large",
                                    "height": "1500px"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            json_api = json.dumps(sendTeams)
            _teams = "Sample WebHook Address..." # this code is sample
            res = requests.post(_teams, data=json_api, headers=headers)
```

When using the existing Teams, the image appears well, but when switching to New Teams, the image does not appear.

I think it's because the version of adaptivecard in NewTeams is not compatible, but I'm not sure the exact reason.

I want to know the exact reason why this error occurs and how to improve it.

If you have a friend who encounters the same error, I'll wait for your comments.

thank you

The post can also be found at the link.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/d0b42c6b-db7e-ee11-a81c-000d3ae46fcb

If you are using adaptivecards in Microsoft Teams and change to the new teams version, an error occurs where adaptivecards does not appear.

Comment: We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. Please do verify.